# How you can put 6 values when overloading an operator? But values also can be added after?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Okay, I am aware it seems complicated.
To start with the code has to take 2 string 2 int numbers and smash them together depending on input then out put result just like:

input:
Dave
8
Jessica
7

output:
Dave & Jessica
15

I tried many times with different approaches but none  seems to work :(

I tried  putting name1 or name2 like strings to DancerPoints Class but I can't find a way to connect with input I mean it is there but can't get input.

I also tried putting values in to the parameter directly but it said operator just can take 2 values but I need 6! 4 for dancers values 2 for management.

At this point it only gets the firstdancer's string and int and use it but I don't get how to add seconddancer's values.

I am working on this for 3 nights I don't know what else to do? :(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Code_Coach_Challenge
{
    class Program
    {
        // I tried putting values here with public but why that not workked I dont know :(

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int points1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            string name2 = Console.ReadLine();
            int points2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            DancerPoints dancer1 = new DancerPoints(name1, points1);
            DancerPoints dancer2 = new DancerPoints(name2, points2);

            DancerPoints total = dancer1 + dancer2;
            Console.WriteLine(total.name);
            Console.WriteLine(total.points);
        }
    }

    class DancerPoints
    {
        public string name;
        public int points;
                            // I tried putting values here no luck.error CS7036
        public DancerPoints(string name, int points)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.points = points;
                                  // I tried putting values here no luck.error CS7036
        }

        //overload the + operator
        public static DancerPoints operator+ (DancerPoints n, DancerPoints p)
        {
                                     // I tried putting values here no luck.error CS7036
            string name = n.name + " & " + n.name;
            int points = p.points + p.points;
           
            DancerPoints res = new DancerPoints(name, points);

            return res;
            
  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific need for the `DancerPoints` class?

Comment: You might be misplaced the variables. Override method has some mistakes in that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator overload should be:

```
public static DancerPoints operator+ (DancerPoints n, DancerPoints p)
    {
        string name = n.name + " & " + p.name;
        int points = n.points + p.points;
       
        DancerPoints res = new DancerPoints(name, points);

        return res;
    }
```

Notice how I changed an n into a p and a p into an n.
This way both n and p's name and point values are used.

Comment: Dude, that what I am looking for.I am just a stupid guy man. this is genius

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a lot of this code down if all you want the program to do is

1. Ask for Name1
2. Ask for Points1
3. Ask for Name2
4. Ask for Points2
5. Print `{Name1} & {Name2} {Points1 + Points2}`

```
string name1 = Console.ReadLine();
int points1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string name2 = Console.ReadLine();
int points2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

string output = $"{name1} & {name2} {points1 + points2}"
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Just simple string concatenation. No need for any fancy classes or operator overloads.

---

Now, if you wanted to expand your code to do more than two people at a time, then

```
class Dancer
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Score {get;set;}
}

var dancers = new List<Dancer>
{
    new Dancer { Name = "David", Score = 8 },
    new Dancer { Name = "Jessica", Score = 7 },
    new Dancer { Name = "Sally", Score = 6 },
}

var allNames = string.Join(" & ", dancers.Select(x => x.Name));
var totalScore = dancers.Sum(x => x.Score);
var output = $"{allNames} {totalScore}"
```

With this example you'd get

```
David & Jessica & Sally 21
```

Again, no need for operator overloading. It doesn't really make sense to "add" dancers together into a new "Dancer" object.

Comment: Dude, thanks for your code and thought but I really take this project to understand operator overloading. But your code will show coders and me deeper understanding :D